# $n$th derivative of $f(x)^{n+1}$

Tags: derivatives, summation

> Hello, I'm trying to find the $n$th derivative of a function, where $n\in\mathbb N$
>   $$\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}} \!\!\left[f(x)^n\right]$$
>   I'm looking for some kind of sum or product (or nesting of these) which gives the value above.

So I tried evaluating the function at some values of $n$

$$
\begin{array}{lr}
f(x) & \text{for  } n=1\\
2f(x)f^{(1)}(x) & n=2\\
3f(x)^2f^{(2)}(x)+6f(x)f^{(1)}(x)^2&n=3\\
4f(x)f^{(4)}+24f(x)f^{(1)}(x)+\cdots\\
\qquad36f(x)^2f^{(1)}(x)f^{(2)}(x) & n=4
\end{array}
$$

---

Some things I noticed was

**1**. In expanded form, it always had a term of the form

$$nf(x)^{n-1}f^{(n-1)}(x)$$

**2**. In expanded form you could always factor out $nf(x)$ from all terms

**3**. $f$ is always multiplied together with itself (or a derivative of itself) $n$ times in each term.

**4**. There's always $n-1$ terms, in the case of $n=1$ it seems to be the always being there factor of $nf(x)$ multiplied with the empty product.

---

Tip: I have found the wolfram alpha input `D[f[x]^n, {x,n-1}], n -> (insert n here)` very useful for calculating the $n$'th version of this formula.

Note: The notation below means the $m$th derivative of $f$

$$f^{(m)}(x)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a formula for

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left(f(g(x))\right) $$

(this suits you). This is called Faà di Bruno's formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula, use it properly and you will get a result

Comment: Thinking a bit about it it seems like this should be the function: $$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(n+1-k)_k~f(x)^{n-k}~B_{n-1,k}\left(f^{(1)}(x), f^{(2)}(x), \dots, f^{n-k}(x)\right)$$

Comment: Yes, now this stuff seems to be correct,the previous was weird

Comment: I think no, this is a very specific case, general must be more useful for everyone